# a11ychecker: Uncaught Error: Tests could not be loaded

Tags: javascript, ajax, ckeditor, accessibility, ckeditor4.x

I'm using a11ychecker for CKEditor 4 and it's working fine on my localhost, but when I upload it to the live website it's not working anymore and I get errors.

When I click the icon on the toolbar, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Tests could not be loaded
    at Object.error (plugin.js?t=I63C:48)
    at u (jquery-3.3.1.min.js?ver=4.9.8:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery-3.3.1.min.js?ver=4.9.8:2)
    at k (jquery-3.3.1.min.js?ver=4.9.8:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js?ver=4.9.8:2)
```

And when I click it again, I get:

```
plugin.js?t=I63C:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFocused' of null
    at t._selectIssue (plugin.js?t=I63C:18)
    at t.hide (plugin.js?t=I63C:17)
    at u.close (plugin.js?t=I63C:40)
    at u.exec (plugin.js?t=I63C:38)
    at r (plugin.js?t=I63C:43)
    at CKEDITOR.command.i (plugin.js?t=I63C:43)
    at CKEDITOR.command.exec (ckeditor.js:212)
    at a.execCommand (ckeditor.js:283)
    at CKEDITOR.ui.button.CKEDITOR.tools.extend.click (ckeditor.js:679)
    at Object.execute (ckeditor.js:680)
t._selectIssue @ plugin.js?t=I63C:18
hide @ plugin.js?t=I63C:17
u.close @ plugin.js?t=I63C:40
u.exec @ plugin.js?t=I63C:38
r @ plugin.js?t=I63C:43
i @ plugin.js?t=I63C:43
exec @ ckeditor.js:212
execCommand @ ckeditor.js:283
CKEDITOR.tools.extend.click @ ckeditor.js:679
execute @ ckeditor.js:680
(anonymous) @ ckeditor.js:681
(anonymous) @ ckeditor.js:31
callFunction @ ckeditor.js:32
```

As you see I have jQuery 3.3.1 and balloonpanel plugin, But I get these errors.

How to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

For my case, it is due to the server gives 404 error for those Quail testing .json files. Adding MIME types in IIS for .json file (application/json) fixes the issue for me.